# Why are my alphabetic characters not being added to the stack when using Character.isAlphabetic()?

Tags: java, stack

My code if preferred in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PtmxnY4P).

I am doing a homework task for Java. Basically the point of the program is to determine whether a sentence string is a palindrome (and it must use stacks to accomplish this). If the sentence contains punctuation etc. it should be removed, i.e.

"Madam, I'm Adam"

would be changed and compared using:

"madamimadam"

So that is what will be done before testing if it's a palindrome. I have another version which works fine for words with no punctuation, e.g. "eye".

Anyway, one part of my code is causing me an empty stack exception - which I believe means the stack I am storing the string to is empty / it's not being stored (the task requires use of stacks). This only happens when I am using the "isAlphabetic()" function. When I remove it, it returns false, which is further down in my code. Basically I am not understanding why the part in the loop where it checks if the string character is alphabetic or not is not pushing alphabetic values onto the stack. It seems it doesn't push anything, hence the empty stack exception. If I remove that part, it does push onto the stack, but it returns false (which is correct, because "e'ye" would not be considered a palindrome, but I need to rid the punctuation so that it is a palindrome and it returns true). Any insight is appreciated, thanks!

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class PalindromesSubmission {
    /**
     * Returns true if word is a palindrome, false if not
     */

public static void main(String[] args) {
//testing the function with different words

    String word = "eye"; //true
    String word2 = "Eye"; //true
    String word3 = "no"; //false
    String word4 = "e'ye"; //empty stack exception
    String word5 = ""; //true
    String word8 = "Madam, I'm Adam";

    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word));
    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word2));
    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word3));
    System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word4));
    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word5));
    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word6));
    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word7));
    //System.out.println(isPalindromeSentence(word8));

}

  public static boolean isPalindromeSentence(String sentence) {

        sentence = sentence.toLowerCase();

        System.out.println(sentence); //for testing purposes
        Stack<Character> first = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            if(Character.isAlphabetic(sentence.charAt(i))) {

                first.push(sentence.charAt(i));
            }

        }

        Stack<Character> firstCopy = new Stack<Character>();
        firstCopy.addAll(first);

        Stack<Character> second = new Stack<Character>();

        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
            second.push(first.pop());
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < firstCopy.size(); i++) {
            //if firstCopy.first() == second.first() then pop both and continue. else return false.

            char a = firstCopy.pop();
            char b = second.pop();

            if(a != b) {

                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;

    };

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to pop `sentence.length()` characters off of `first`:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        second.push(first.pop());
    }
```

But you didn't necessarily push that many characters onto `first`.  If there were some non-alphabetic characters in your original `sentence`, you pushed **fewer than** `sentence.length()` characters onto `first'.

The solution is to pop characters from `first` until `first` tells you it has no more characters to pop:

```
 while (!first.isEmpty()) {
        second.push(first.pop());
    }
```

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. Thank you so much!